# Windows - what happens to file, locked over the network, when locker process crash

Tags: windows, file-locking

Consider a process running on "local" machine, which locks the file in windows shared folder (i.e. the file located on another, "remote", machine).

What will happen to a file if "local" process crashed, or even local PC shutdown, or network failure happened? I.e. nobody explicitly unlocked the file - so will it, how and when will be unlocked?

All involved machines running windows.

Comment: This probably belongs to superuser..

Comment: it's a question from developer. we are developing applications which going to run on several machines and access some files via the network. we are planning to synchronize access using file locks. the question is to understand whether it's reliable?

Comment: It still belongs to superuser. The question isn't about programming, it's a general question about filesystems and networks, therefore: `question` **-to->** `superuser`.

Comment: Create a text file, save it on the network and kill -9 your process. That quick test will give you an idea of what is happening. Back on Superuser, please name all OS involved at both ends

Comment: if the client process crashes, then the kernel automatically closes open handles. If the client computer shuts down abruptly (e.g. power loss), then the recovery depends on the network protocol. SMB has a [Session Expiration Timer Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246788%28v=prot.13%29.aspx) for example.